# issue with like in php mysqli

Tags: php, mysql

Whats wrong with this code?:

```
SELECT alias FROM Articls 
WHERE (title LIKE '%key%' 
OR sections LIKE '%key%' 
OR description LIKE '%key%' 
OR category LIKE '%key%' 
OR subcategory LIKE '%key%) 
AND MATCH (content) AGAINST ('key') 
GROUP BY alias ORDER BY alias DESC LIMIT 500
```

but I got an error...So I simplified that code to this:

```
SELECT alias  FROM Articls 
WHERE (title LIKE '%key%' 
OR content LIKE '%key%' 
OR sections LIKE '%key%' 
OR description LIKE '%key%' 
OR category LIKE '%key%' 
OR subcategory LIKE '%key%) 
ORDER BY alias DESC LIMIT 500
```

But I still get an error:

> Warning: mysqli_fetch_all() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result,
>   boolean given in
>   /home/admin/domains/example.com/public_html/lib/core/p.php on line
>   141 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''%news%)

Comment: The syntax highlighting (color coding) here indicates where you are missing a quote. Do you see it?

Comment: ooo a where's waldo game! It's after subcategory LIKE '%key%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were missing an apostrophe at the end of the final LIKE statement.

```
SELECT alias  FROM Articls 
WHERE (title LIKE '%key%' 
OR content LIKE '%key%' 
OR sections LIKE '%key%' 
OR description LIKE '%key%' 
OR category LIKE '%key%' 
OR subcategory LIKE '%key%') 
ORDER BY alias DESC 
LIMIT 500
```